# CSV compare with JSON

Tags: java, json, csv

let's say i have two CSV file. file 1 defines standard csv data file & File 2 is the mapping file of file 1 & Json
now what i want is i want to map those two files and compare the data of File 1 with the Json. & output the mismatch as a csv.

how do i achieve that?

File 1:

```
key,id,value,name,number
1,322,re43,dasu,555-456
```

File 2:

```
Rsat_key,key
Retina_id,id
reason_value,value
real_name,name
work_ph,phone
```

Json

```
{
    "Rsat_key":1,
    "Retina_id":322,
    "reason_value":,
    "real_name":dasu,
    "work_ph":,555-456,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will look like

```
 String csvFile = "sample.csv";
 BufferedReader br = null;
 String line = "";
 String cvsSplitBy = ",";
 try {
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
 // use comma as separator
 String[] result = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
 System.out.println(" { Rsat_key: " + result[0] 
 + " , Retina_id:" + result[1] + ", reason_value:"+result[2]+", real_name:"+result[3]+", work_ph:"++result[4]+"}");
 }
```

If you want to dynamically assign the keys from the csv then you will have to read that csv also.

Comment: well this is a sample files i have give over here. the real files are way too large to assign manually. all i am searching now how to map the two csv file & obviously not manually.

Comment: r u going to expose theis JSON as web service??

Comment: i am actually trying to do that only.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bean some thing like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee") 
public class Employee {
@XmlElement  
private String employeeId;  
@XmlElement  
private String employeeName; 
@XmlElement  
private String jobType;
@XmlElement     
private String address; 
@XmlElement  
private Long salary;

//setter and getter
```

and assign the values to the bean and if you are using restful web service  using @Produces("application/json") annotation  in the end point will generate JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be to create object models and use google gson (for json), and beanio (for csv), to serialize and de-serialize objects.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

http://beanio.org/

for example with gson

```
public class Model1 {
   String field1;
   //getters and setters
}
```

then

```
Model1 model1 = new Gson().fromJson(YourfileReader);
```

is the same idea with beanio.

You can take it further and add equal methods on your objects to help with easy lookups.

hope it gives you inspiration.